# iOS how to import assets from one project to another project

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a free sample code from the internet, it uses Appicons and I would like to use them

(the code is free and open source)

I don't know how to copy the photos from that project to my project

off i know how to add assets but how can i know that this photo is for this model.

because as you see there are many options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to drag the file assets from the finder window to the asset view in Xcode, or from one asset view window in Xcode to the other asset view window.  By the way, you should supply assets for all of the models of device you plan to support (all iPhone models, all iPad models or both).